# Ghostscript renders embedded fonts in pdf poorly (all jaggy)

Tags: pdf, rendering, ghostscript

Ghostscript doesn't render embedded fonts in pdf's properly.
e.g. http://vegro.nl/cmsfiles/ConsumentenAssortiment/Brochure/10.axd
The characters of the logo on the right top ('Thermrad') are all jagged.
If I open the file in Adobe Reader, no problem at all!

Do you have this problem too? Is there any solution?
I've been searching for days now, but I cannot find anything.

I tried Ghostscript 8.64 and 8.71 both on Windows Vista and CentOS.

Comment: Which is the commandline you used for Ghostscript? And what the hell is an .axd file? -- BTW, for me the thingie doesn't open in Reader 9.3.3 -- it says *"File could not be loaded through network... Maybe corrupt?"*

Comment: Also, what do you want to achieve with Ghostscript. You have a PDF -- so what do you want ghostscript to convert it to?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to use Ghostscript 8.71. Then use this commandline:

```
  gswin32c.exe ^
      -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
      -o thermrad-out.pdf ^
      -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer ^
      10.axd
```

That should do the job of converting the PDF to one that has no problems any more. Because the original .axd file does have a problem with an embedded font. (I'm using `pdffonts.exe` from the XPDF suite to check). The problem occurs on page 3 of your 10.axd:

```
 for /l %i in (1,1,16) do (
       echo.   ............ Page %i ............................... ^
       & pdffonts.exe -f %i -l %i 10.axd ^
       & echo.)
```

outputs this:

```
  [....]
        ............ Page 3 ...............................
  name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
  ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes    249  0
  XCZBKH+HelveticaNeue-Light           Type 1C           yes yes yes    250  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     15  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     19  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     41  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     45  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     49  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     53  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     57  0
  Error: Illegal entry in bfchar block in ToUnicode CMap
  YCRHYF+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes yes     61  0
  [....]
```

After I let Ghostscript repair it, the problem is gone for page 3 in the repaired PDF:

```
 c:\> pdffonts.exe -f 3 -l 3 thermrad.pdf

   name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
   ------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
   CZBBTM+HelveticaNeue-LightExt        Type 1C           yes yes no      13  0
   MXETZY+HelveticaNeue-Light           Type 1C           yes yes no      40  0
```

Comment: Updating my DLL to 9.16 fixed my issue with colors and fonts! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cure for smooth font rendering for us when converting PDF to JPG was to turn on text anti-aliasing with `-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4`.

Here's a windows batch file I use to convert to a [page size](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Use.htm#Known_paper_sizes) passed on the command line. Sample invocation: `pdf2jpg infile.pdf 11x17`

```
gswin64c.exe ^
-dNOPAUSE -P- -dSAFER -dBATCH ^
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 ^
-dTextAlphaBits=4 ^
-sDEVICE=jpeg ^
-dJPEGQ=85 ^
-r300x300 ^
-sPAGESIZE=%2^
-sOutputFile=%~n1.jpg ^
%1
```

Also there is at least one [known issue](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=689044) with font anti-aliasing being turned off automatically in some gs versions if transparent images are present. [Convert a PDF to a Transparent PNG with GhostScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977540/convert-a-pdf-to-a-transparent-png-with-ghostscript) has a solution.