# How to programatically convert pdf to png in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, vb.net-2010

Is there a library or code somewhere that does that?

Some questions suggest software like [Convert a PDF to a Transparent PNG with GhostScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977540/convert-a-pdf-to-a-transparent-png-with-ghostscript)

I need something that's done by program. So my site, which is an asp site, should have a function

```
function PNGfromPDF (someFile as String) as PNGSomething
end function
```

Something like that.

Any open source solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(fileNames[i], PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

                        // for each page create a new PDF file and save it on the disk
                        for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < inputDocument.PageCount; pageCount++)
                        {
    fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNames[i]);
                                fileName = string.Format("{0}\\Documents\\{1}", Session.CentralWorkingDirectory, String.Format("{0} ({1}-{2}).pdf", fileNameWithoutExtension, pageCount + 1, inputDocument.PageCount));

    pdfFile = PDFFile.Open(fileName);
                pdfFile.SerialNumber = Configurations.PDFVIEW_KEY;

                // Get image file name
                string imageFileName = string.Format("{0}.png", fileName.Remove(fileName.Length - 4));

                // If thumbnail already exists delete it
                if (File.Exists(imageFileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(imageFileName);
                }

                // Convert page to PNG and save it.
                //Bitmap pageImage = pdfFile.GetPageImage(0, 32);


                Bitmap pageImage = pdfFile.GetPageImage(0, 92);
                pageImage.Save(imageFileName, ImageFormat.Png);

                // Cleanup resources
                pageImage.Dispose();
                pdfFile.Dispose();


    }
```

Here I am using below namespace...

```
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using O2S.Components.PDFRender4NET; // Thrid party components so you use PDF sharp with this componets
 using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```